# The SetFocusable function does not work for me in an API where it should work for me

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I have this code below, everything works great for Android 9

```
RespM= FindViewById<RecyclerView>(Resource.Id.RespMedius);
RespM.SetFocusable(ViewFocusability.NotFocusable);
```

But when I want to try it in an **API 17** I get the following error, since it is assumed that the function `SetFocusable` is inside the **API 14** should work for me ... any solution?

> **Java.Lang.NoSuchMethodError:** 'no method with name='setFocusable' signature='(I)V' in class Landroid/view/View;'

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`SetFocusable(int focusable)` was added in API-26.

> Setting this to NOT_FOCUSABLE will ensure that this view is also not focusable in touch mode.

`SetFocusable(boolean focusable)` was added in API-1.

Since you are using `NotFocusable`, you can use:

```
someView.SetFocusable(false);
someView.SetFocusableInTouchMode(false);
```